# Android listview with images from database

Tags: android

i am trying to display detail from a database using listview in android and i am geting this error. i created a custom listadapter and i am having errors. below is my code. i tried to do it with picasso and i couid not do it. so i tried it this way and it is not working......

```
package com.example.cann;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CategoryActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "category";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT = "categories_count";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO = "categories_logo";

    private static final String URL_CATEGORY = "http://10.0.2.2/music/selectm.php";

    // albums JSONArray
    JSONArray categories = null;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // private ListView lv;
    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Log.d("onCreate: ", "Yep");


        new LoadComments().execute();
    }

    public void yess(){
        // get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setDivider(null);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, "Item selected: " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Uncomment this to start a new Activity for a chosen item
                /* Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ItemListActivity.class);

                String category_id = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.category_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                i.putExtra("category_id", category_id);

                startActivity(i);*/
            }
        });
    }
    public void upd(){

        categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();    
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_CATEGORY);
        try {

            categories  = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c =categories.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT);
                String category_logo = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT, songs_count);
                map.put(TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO, category_logo);

                categoryList.add(map);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList

                }

                mAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,
                        categoryList);
                getListView().setAdapter(mAdapter);

                // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
                pDialog.dismiss();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            upd();
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            yess();
        }
    }


}




package com.example.cann;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CategoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> urls;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static final String CATEGORY_LOGO_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/demi.jpg";

    public CategoryListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {
        mContext = context;
        urls = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView category_name;
        ImageView category_logo;
        TextView item_count;
        TextView item_id;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_category, parent,
                false);

        resultp = urls.get(position);

        category_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        category_logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_category_logo);
        item_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songs_count);
        item_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_id);

        category_name.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_NAME));
        item_count.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT));
        item_id.setText(resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_ID));

        // Picasso image loader library starts here
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(CATEGORY_LOGO_URL
                        + resultp.get(CategoryActivity.TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO)) // Photo URL
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) // This image will be displayed while photo URL is loading
                .error(R.drawable.error) // if error shows up during downloading
                .fit().centerCrop() // settings
                .into(category_logo); // we put it into our layout component (imageview)

        return view;
    }

}
```

and it gives me errors

```
09-09 09:51:18.549: I/Choreographer(1476): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-09 09:51:20.299: W/dalvikvm(1476): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a59ba8)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476): Process: com.example.cann, PID: 1476
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:857)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4320)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10935)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10890)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1937)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:521)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at com.example.cann.CategoryActivity.upd(CategoryActivity.java:122)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at com.example.cann.CategoryActivity$LoadComments.doInBackground(CategoryActivity.java:147)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at com.example.cann.CategoryActivity$LoadComments.doInBackground(CategoryActivity.java:1)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-09 09:51:21.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1476):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate views on a non-UI thread.

Instead, I would suggest you to set your adapter and dismiss the dialog (as found in **upd** method) in Async's `onPostExecute` method - which is the right way to perform such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `yess()` from `onPostExecute` and put in `onCreate()` after executing Asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

give like this  @Override
   `     protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
          private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() 
            { 
                //* The Complete ProgressBar does not appear**/
              Udp();
            } 
        }); 
return null;
    }

```
    }`
```

Comment: it is telling runnable can not be instantiate